# How to solve the following warning from brew doctor?

Tags: osx, homebrew

MacOS Sierra 10.12.2

Recently, I ran into the following issue:

```
Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
  /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.la
```

I have tried different approaches like:

```
brew unlink postgresql && brew link postgresql
brew link --overwrite postgresql
```

But that doesnt seem to resove the warning.

appreciate any help

Comment: I'm not sure this is actually a brewing question - as much as a software usage/debugging question. If the file is not supposed to be there then why not try:

rm /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.la

Make a backup first just in case.....

Comment: If you are sure you don't need this file, just delete it and the warning will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed PostgreSQL via Homebrew and you don't want to keep another PostgreSQL installation in parallel. You can safely delete the file with:

```
rm /usr/local/lib/psqlodbcw.la
```

and the warning will disappear.